# HTML5 Audio Tag can't be played on android

Tags: android, html, audio

I want to write an HTML page, that can play some audio files. I use this code:

```
<audio width="100%" controls >
<source src="sprachMemo.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
<source src="sprachMemo.m4a" type="audio/x-aac" />
<source src="sprachMemo.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
<source src="sprachMemo.wav" type="audio/wav" />
Problem!
</audio>
```

When I open the page with Chrome and a PC it work. But on the mobile, it shows the audio file, but you can not play it. So it just shows, that there is a file used.

I have also been looking for other solutions , but want to have a simple variant. And as I could see, the system worked on other sites.

How can I make it work on Android, too?

Comment: Can you play the file with another player in your mobile ?

Comment: Yes I can. I have tried it by including an download.